# How To Stop FrameAnimation And launch a new Activity ??(Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation

```
 public class Mainpage extends Activity {

// Declaring an Image View and an Animation Drawable
    ImageView view;
    ImageView view1;
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

        // Typecasting the Image View
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);


        // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);

        // Typecasting the Animation Drawable
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
    }

    // Called when Activity becomes visible or invisible to the user
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            // Starting the animation when in Focus
            frameAnimation.start();
        } else {
            // Stoping the animation when not in Focus
            frameAnimation.stop();
        }
    }

 }
```

Is There any method to stop Frame animation and Launch An activity/Intent After that ??

i tried to search this query on google but most of the code consists Start and Stop button to stop Frame Animation ...need A query without button ..Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes `frameAnimation.stop();` method is used to stop animation. And for start new `Activity` you can use the following code-

```
startActivity(Mainpage.this, newActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

you can use the `Activity` name you want to start in place of `newActivity`.

Comment: Ty but i already tried this !! whenever i pressed back button ..then frame animation stopped and new activity started....i need a counter of frame animation and whenever animation hits at given counter it will have to stop the frame animation and will launch the new activity !!

Comment: you need handler to do this. you want to pause animation then new activity start?

Comment: sort of i just want to show animation once and then next activity/Intent !!

Comment: final Handler handle = new Handler();
        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            frameAnimation.start();
            }
        };
        handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);

Comment: @Xy1ys you can use this code to do something for particular time like i write frameAnimation.start(); in run method. its show animation for 3 seconds.

Comment: @Xy1ys then use timer and on finish call stopAnimation() and then your new activity.

Comment: sorry call frameAnimation.stop();